# returning data in app script from an HTML input

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, html-select

I am trying to lauch an html form from a google spread sheet using the HTMLService and return data to the script from a select input.  I am collecting the data with this line:
-

But I am not sure how to get it back to the script file:  I have tried various iterations of:
-      city= form.Projects_list.text;
-      city= form.Projects_list[0];
-      city= form.Projects_list.[0][0];

but none of these seem to be the right handle to the select.  The other variables are coming back from the form as desired.

How can I grab that last variable?

**HTML File**

```
<b>Add Row To Spreadsheet</b><br />

    <form>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );

  $( function() {
    $( ".widget input[type=submit]" ).button();
    $( "button, input, a" ).click( function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
    } );
  } );
  </script>


 <form id = "dateform">
 <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name ="datepicker"></p><p></p>
    Reason for Delay: <input id="reason" name="reason" type="text" />

    Last name: <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" />

   <input onclick="formSubmit()" type="button" value="Add Row" />
   <input onclick="google.script.host.close()" type="button" value="Exit" />

  <hr>
  <div id = 'pList'>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Select A City</td><td><select id="Projects_list"name ="Projects_list"></select></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
   </div>


   </form>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function formSubmit() {
            google.script.run.getValuesFromForm(document.forms[0]);
            google.script.host.close();
        }

  </script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">

    // Client-side JavaScript that uses the list returned by
    // GAS function "getValuesForRngName()" to populate the dropdown.
    // This is standard client-side JavaScript programming that uses
    // DOM manipulation to get page elements and manipulate them.
    function onSuccess(values) {
      var opt,
          dropDown;
        for(i = 0;i < values.length; i +=1){
          dropDown = document.getElementById("Projects_list");
          opt = document.createElement("option");
          dropDown.options.add(opt);
          // Remember that GAS Range method "GetValues()" returns
          // an array of arrays, hence two array indexes "[i][0]" here.
          opt.text = values[i][0];
          opt.value = values[i][0];

       }
    }
    function populate(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getValuesForRngName('Projects20');
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    // Using the "load" event to execute the function "populate"
    window.addEventListener('load', populate);

  </script>

  <script>
    // Client-side JavaScript that uses the list returned by
    // GAS function "getValuesForRngName()" to populate the dropdown.
    // This is standard client-side JavaScript programming that uses
    // DOM manipulation to get page elements and manipulate them.
    function onSuccessx(values) {
      var opt,
          dropDown;
        for(i = 0;i < values.length; i +=1){
          dropDown = document.getElementById("Projects_list");
          opt = document.createElement("option");
          dropDown.options.add(opt);
          // Remember that GAS Range method "GetValues()" returns
          // an array of arrays, hence two array indexes "[i][0]" here.
          opt.text = values[i][0];
          opt.value = values[i][0];
       }
       dropDown = dropDown.options.sort()
    }
    function populatex(){
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getValuesForRngName('Projects20');
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    // Using the "load" event to execute the function "populate"
    window.addEventListener('loadx', populate);
  </script>
```

**App Script File**

```
function demoHtmlServices() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('changeDateHTML');
  setRngName();
  ss.show(html);

}

//getValuesFromForm
function getValuesFromForm(form){
  var firstName = form.firstName,
      lastName = form.lastName,
      reason = form.reason,
      newDate = form.datepicker,
      city= form.Projects_list.text;
      sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Test');
  sheet.appendRow([lastName, reason, newDate, city]);
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi() ;
  alert('Test');
  ui.alert('form.Projects_list(0)')

  google.script.host.close();
  }

// Display the GUI
// Execute this function from the script editor ro run the application.
// Note the call to "setRngName()". This ensures that all newly added
// values are included in the dropdown list when the GUI is displayed
function displayGUI() {
  var ss,
      html;
  setRngName();
  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  ss.show(html);
}
// Called by Client-side JavaScript in the index.html.
// Uses the range name argument to extract the values.
// The values are then sorted and returned as an array
// of arrays.
function getValuesForRngName(rngName) {
  var rngValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(rngName).getValues();
  return rngValues.sort();
}

//Expand the range defined by the name as rows are added
function setRngName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sh = ss.getSheetByName('DropdownValues'),
      firstCellAddr = 'A2',
      dataRngRowCount = sh.getDataRange().getLastRow(),
      listRngAddr = (firstCellAddr + ':A' + dataRngRowCount),
      listRng = sh.getRange(listRngAddr);
  ss.setNamedRange('20Projects', listRng);
  //Logger.log(ss.getRangeByName('Cities').getValues());
}

// For debugging
function test_setRngName() {
  setRngName();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the value attribute.

```
document.getElementById("Projects_list").value
```

Comment: Thanks Amit.     How do I pass document back to the original script file.

Comment: Amit Agarwal I have tried inserting this line in the HTML file and the Script file in various ways.   How do I get a handle on this in the script file that called the html?